# Отправка файлов на php через ajax

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, ftp

Доброго времени суток! Есть некоторая форма, которая передает сообщение. Передавала она на server.php таким кодом:

```js
function sendAjaxForm(infoBox, addUser, url) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:     'server.php', 
        type:     "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        data: jQuery("#"+addUser).serialize(), 
        success: function(response) { 
            result = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
            document.getElementById(infoBox).innerHTML += "<tr><td><b>"+result.name+"</b></td></tr><tr><td>"+result.msg+"</td></tr>";// ИСПРАВИТЬ
        },
        error: function(response) { // Данные не отправлены
            document.getElementById(infoBox).innerHTML = "Ошибка. Данные не отправленны.";
        }
    });
}
```

Теперь я захотел присоединять к сообщению еще и файлы через

```html
<input type='file' name='msgFile'>
```

Вопрос: как изменить скрипт (1) чтобы на server.php улетал еще и файл с последующей загрузкой через FTP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form action="action" method="post" class="cl_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

jQuery('.cl_form').submit(function(e)
{
//e.preventDefault();
var formData = new FormData($(this).get(0));
jQuery.ajax({
    [...]
            data:formData,
            cache:false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
    [...]
});
return false;
});
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что данный скрипт все равно перезагрузит страницу?

Comment: добавьте `e.preventDefault();` перед `var formData = ...`

Comment: Спасибо, работает, но к сожалению все равно открывает URL из `url: 'server.php'`

Comment: в конце `.submit(function(e){......})` (во внутренней функции, разумеется) добавьте `return false;`

Answer (score 0):

Можно [так](http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-file-upload-tutorial.html)

Можно [еще и так](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) , но это через XMLHttpRequest.